# Как сделать функцию с необязательным параметром в СИ

Tags: c, функции

Имеется функция вида

```
f(p1, *p2, *p3, *p4) {
   ...
}
```

По указателям p3 и p4 присваиваются определённые значения, которые не всегда нужны во внешней программе, т.е. эти аргументы, в отличие от p1 и p2, являются не обязательными. Как можно реализовать на Си, чтобы можно было использовать эту функцию без "возвращения" значений туда, на что указывают p3 и p4?

Например, чтобы можно было использовать как f(a1, &a2), так и f(a1, &a2, a3, a4)

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду функции с переменным числом параметров, то почитайте `man stdarg`.

(там есть пример, если что-то останется неясным -- спросите).

Comment: Вот [ещё подход](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926165/276994).

Comment: @VladD, действительно интересные ответы (в т.ч. непосредственно следующий за Вашей ссылкой).

А самым интересным окажется, если ТС имеет в виду вот что:

    Есть функция с 4-мя параметрами, помещающая результаты по адресам 3-го и 4-го аргументов, код которой я не могу менять. 

    Требуется научиться вызывать ее так, чтобы вызванная с двумя параметрами, она не пыталать ничего писать по несуществующим адресам.

На самом деле, наверное, можно какой-то wrapper придумать и тут.

Comment: @VladD спасибо! Хотя я уже немного изучил тему. А разве va_end уже не надо использовать перед выходом из функции?

Comment: @Ilyazh, va_end? 

Конечно, надо. 

Не знаю, почему-то пропал при копипасте и вырвнивании.

Comment: @avp: Удивительно, как много можно сделать с казалось бы таким примитивным препроцессором.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[@Ilyazh](/users/22381/ilyazh)](/users/22381/ilyazh), если еще актуально, то вот пример такой функции (из рабочей программы в Linux)

```
static int 
check_args_nz(void *a, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, a);

  int i;
  for (i = 0; a; i++)
    a = va_arg(ap, void *);

  va_end(ap);
  return i;
}
```

Для теста вызывать можно примерно так:

```
  int a = 1;
  char *b = "abc";
  double c;

  printf ("%d %d %d\n", 
          check_args_nz(0, "2", &a, 0),
          check_args_nz(&a, b, &b, &c, 0),
          check_args_nz((void *)a, 0));
```

результат:

```
$ ./a.out 
0 4 1
$
```

Comment: @avp: Раз ваш комментарий сконвертировали в ответ, может быть стоит добавить `va_end` для будущих поколений любителей copy/paste?

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, поправил.

--

А по поводу вопроса, я на самом деле не очень понимаю, зачем вообще нужно моделировать function overloading в C. 

Для красоты кода?

--

В реальной программе всегда же можно плюс к `f(a1, a2, a3, a4)` написать функцию

    type f2 (type a1, type a2) { 
       type a3, a4; 
       return f(a1, a2, &a3, &4);
    }

которую и вызывать в нужном месте. Просто и понятно.

Comment: @avp: Я считаю, что ни function overloading, ни необязательные параметры в C не нужны.

В отличие от C++, который любит, чтобы один и тот же синтаксис выражал различную семантику (напр. разыменование указателя или доступ к элементу по итератору выглядят одинаково), философия C состоит в том, что _как можно меньше_ вещей происходят неявно, чтобы программист понимал, чего стоит выполнение кода по самому коду.

Поэтому невидимая подстановка неуказанных аргументов «за сценой» совсем не ложится на философию C.

Answer (score 0):

Рискую оказаться не прав, давно с С дела не имел :)

```
f(p1, *p2, *p3, *p4 = NULL) {
//проверка p3 и p4 на  NULL
}

f(p1,*p2,*p3 = NULL) {
    f(pi,p2,p3,NULL);
}

//можно использовать
type a, b, c;
f(1, &a);
f(1, &a, &b);
f(1, &a, &b, &c);
```

Comment: Это в C++ так. В чистом C не скомпилируется: http://ideone.com/Y6ZPOy

Answer (score 0):

Я бы завернул возврат в структуру

```
struct f_result
{
    int* p2;
    int* p3;
    int* p4;
};
void f(int p1, f_result* result);
```

Звать так:

```
int p2; // сюда хотим возвращаемое значение p2
f_params p = {&p2}; // не заданные члены структуры автоматически получают нули
f(100, &p);
```

В синтаксисе могу несколько ошибаться, с голым Си мало дела имел.

Answer (score 0):

А не проще сделать так?

```
void sum_and_product(int p1, int p2, int* p3, int* p4)
{
    if( p3 ) {
        *p3 = p1 + p2;
    }
    if( p4 ) {
        *p4 = p1 * p2;
    }
}

int sum;
int product;

sum_and_product(2, 3, &sum, NULL);
sum_and_product(1, 1, NULL, &product);
```

Answer (score -3):

Пример:
Код:

```
Function MyFunction(S: String): Boolean; OverLoad;
Begin
Form1.Caption:=S;
MyFunction:=True;
End;

Function MyFunction(S1, S2: String): Boolean; OverLoad;
Begin
Form1.Caption:=S1;
Form1.Button1.Caption:=S2;
MyFunction:=True;
End;

Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin
MyFunction('Hello World!');
End;

Procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Begin
MyFunction('My Name Is ...', 'Say SomeThing...');
End;
```

---

I am the First of Cyber Evolution...
I am the First to Program your Future...

Comment: @СЕРГЕЙ: Мы вообще-то тут обсуждаем особенности языка C.